# Invading spaceships land on Earth; aliens have differently coloured helmets

Tags: story-identification, movie

The aliens wear different colored helmets depicting their rank or discipline. Earth is fighting a losing battle.  People find a cave to the aliens' underground headquarters or barracks.  I think some people kill an alien and steal his space suit and the tide turns.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you watch this?  Was it live-action or animated?  Why were the aliens invading?

Comment: What do the aliens look like physically? Like regular humans, very different to humans, or somewhere in-between?

Comment: I don't know, but this sounds a bit like The Mysterians (1957), a famous Japanese invasion from otther space movie.  The Mysterians did establish a base on Earth, which a human entered through an underground passageway, and did wear color coded helmets.  There was also a giant monster, and agrea tfinal fattle.   https://search.yahoo.com/search?fr=mcafee&type=E211US105G0&p=the+mysterians

Comment: The colored helmets immediately made me think of The Mysterians too. Was there a giant robot stomping about causing mayhem?